# Better playback in Sibelius

Tags: untagged

How can I get 'better' sounding playback when composing in Sibelius? Poor (or clearly synthesised) playback puts many people I know off using Sibelius.

Or is this something that varies depending on the operating system, and version of Sibelius?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is old, but it's still relevant, so I'll add that Sibelius supports the Rewire protocol which lets you use it in conjunction with a sequencer like Logic or Digital Performer where you can run your samples in more of a user-friendly way.

Also, if you have the Symphonic Orchestra samples from East West, then you can download a ready-made playback configuration for Sibelius: http://www.soundsetproject.com/soundsets/eastwest/

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't Sibelius support MIDI playback? Just connect a fancy synthesizer or keyboard. ;-) Possibly, it will have to be put in General MIDI mode.

According to the [Sibelius 5 VST info page](http://www.sibelius.com/products/sibelius/5/vst.html), it also supports the [VST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VST_instrument) standard for playing back music with [Software Synthesizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_synthesizer) that you'd install on your OS (only Windows and Mac I'm afraid). There are surely a lot of free ones out there. You'll probably need one that is versatile and can cover all instruments, that means the General MIDI standard.

The ones I am familiar with and I can surely recommend because of their versatility (covering all instruments of the General MIDI standard) are [HALion Sonic](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst/halion_sonic/halion_sonic.html), the quite more complex [HALion 3](http://www.steinberg.net/de/products/vst/halion3_product/start.html) or the older, now kind of obsolete [Hypersonic 2](http://www.steinberg.net/en/support/downloads/hypersonic_2.html).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer, Sibelius supports among other things (and also sells) the Garritan line of instruments samples and there are multiple other choices. I use the Garritan Personal Orchestra package.

Note that apart from "realtime" playback, you can produce enhanced "recorded" playback from Sibelius as a sound file in several formats.